# Hash function sql

Tags: sql, hash, google-bigquery

I want to create a hash column on my table.
I want to put all values of a row in that column like concatenation and replace null with any symbol. And each cell should be separated with a delimiter.

for example

```
A  B    C    D  HashColumn
1  2    Null 4  1/2/_/4
12 Null 4    5  12/_/4/5
```

I want to do this on multiple tables so need a dynamic query for this.

Please tell me how can I do this in bigquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend below simple approach

```
select *, format('%t', t) HashColumn
from your_table t
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Which looks good enough as a hash for me.
But in case if your really need the format you mentioned in the question - you can do some extra string processing  - for example

```
select *, 
  replace(trim(format('%t', t), '()'), 'NULL', '_') HashColumn
from your_table t
```

in this case  - output is

[image]

Comment: Glad it works for you. Please consider also voting up the answer if it helped :o)

Comment: @MikhailBerlynt Done :) I actually want to ask one more thing. Now I want to apply TRIM function to my columns in the first query that you have shared. If I do TRIM(format('%t', t))  it's not working and If I do format('%t', TRIM(t)) it's giving me error as the columns are of different data types and it only supports string and bytes. Can you please tell me a solution for this?

Comment: This approach does not allow you to process individual columns and rather deals with the whole row - this is a beauty of this approach. If you really need apply TRIM on column level - you can use Sergey's answer or if this still does not work for you - please post new question with all relevant details and data sample and we will try to further help you. Ok? :o)

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
select IFNULL(CAST(A as string), '_') || '/' 
    || IFNULL(CAST(B as string), '_') || '/' 
    || IFNULL(CAST(C as string), '_') || '/' 
    || IFNULL(CAST(D as string), '_')
from mytable
```