# TRIM in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery, format, trim

I want to apply TRIM function for my columns. But TRIM after Format function is not working. It's not trimming the spaces.

If I do it before format as below then it gives me error for datatype because the columns have other datatypes than string and byte as well.

Please tell me a solution for this.

Comment: As I mentioned in comments for https://stackoverflow.com/a/70115567/5221944 - This approach does not allow you to process individual columns and rather deals with the whole row - this is a beauty of this approach. If you really need apply TRIM on column level - and you have too many columns to have them all enlisted in select statement - you should consider dynamic sql with EXECUTE IMMEDIATE. Try and if any issue with this  post specific questions with relevant details of what the issue is  - so we will be happy to help

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant How exactly should I use EXECUTE IMMEDIATE? because right now I am storing all this in a variable and using execute immediate variable name. I did not understand how this will solve the problem for trim.

Comment: Hard to put this in comments. I will try to put down some simplified example for you. Ok?

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant Okay. Thanks

Comment: looks like I got easier way to address your question - see my answer below. so no need for dynamic sql - which would be little overengineering here :o)

Answer (score 2):

Meantime, you can apply some extra processing on top of original query to get desired result - as in below example

```
select *, 
  trim(replace(regexp_replace(format('%t', t), r' *, *| *\)|\( *', '/'), '/NULL/', '/_/'), '/') HashColumn
from your_table t
```

if applied to sample data

```
with your_table as (
  select '    1' A, '2    ' B, null C, 4 D union all 
  select '   12   ', null, '4', 5 
)
```

output is

[image]

Comment: Hey This one is giving me error as 'Cannot parse regular expression:: no argument for repetition operation.'

Comment: i have run it again and it perfectly works  - try again but make sure you don't do any changes in the code! Meantime, have you tried approach in second answer?

Comment: It's working. Thanks. I have not tried the approach in second answer yet. Will try it too.

Answer (score 0):

Consider below approach

```
create temp function json_extract_values(input string) returns array<string> language js as """
  return Object.values(JSON.parse(input));""";
select *,
  ( select string_agg(trim(value), '/')
    from unnest(json_extract_values(replace(to_json_string(t), ':null', ':"_"'))) value 
  ) as HashColumn
from your_table t
```

if applied to dummy data as below

```
with your_table as (
  select '    1' A, '2    ' B, null C, 4 D union all 
  select '   12   ', null, '4', 5 
)
```

output is

[image]

which, I hope, is exactly what you are looking for

Comment: Have you tried? Did it work for you?